# Android FFMpeg Rendom File input Command to Create Video Slideshow

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, command, slideshow

The Command for creating video from sequence of images, is not working.i'm using the library writingminds FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2. i have tried the command as given below,

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String path : list){
        builder.append("file '"+path+"' ");
    }
    //List Contains absolute path of images, i have conceited it
    String[] complexCommand = {"-i", builder.toString(), "-vf", "zoompan=d=(A+B)/B:fps=1/B" , "framerate=25:interp_start=0:interp_end=255:scene=100" , "-c:v" , "mpeg4" , "-s", "160x120", "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "150k", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: "zoompan=d=(A+B)/B:fps=1/B" filter. after applying it video becomes unreadable to player.

Comment: `A` and `B` are not valid expressions for zoompan. What are they representing? Show the complete log output from the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: They are representing the time to zoom in/out particular image. i got this command from wiki how. if you want, you can give me example of command. i think i miss- understood the command

Comment: Refer to the [zoompan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan) documentation.